# How to skip blank values of array when updating columns in the database

Tags: php, sql, arrays

I'm a newbie in PHP. I would like to ask on how to skip blank values in an array when updating columns in the database. My code goes this:

```
$reference = $_POST['ref'];
$userDoc = $_POST['userDoc'];
$doc = array_filter($userDoc);
$ref = array_filter($reference);

for($j=0; $j<=sizeof($doc_ent);$j++){
$docu = $doc_ent[$j];
echo $ref[$j];
echo $doc[$j];

$update = sqlsrv_query($conn2, "update stock_picking_se set name = '$internal$ref[$j]', user_doc = '$doc[$j]' where doc_entry = '$docu'");

}
```

My checkbox which filter my data is:

```
checkbox1: a
checkbox2: (blank data)
checbox3:  b
checkbox4: (blank data)
checkbox5: c
```

But when I process, it updates the existing columns but keep inserting the blank value in an array, the result is:

```
column:

name                      user_doc

1                         a

(blank)                   (blank)

2                          b
```

note that `$doc_ent` is the the selected checkboxes. I want the result to insert in the column `name` 1,2,3 and in column `user_doc` a,b,c.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a condition:

```
if($reference != '' && $userDoc != '') { Put your query }
```

Then it automatically skips the blank fields.

Comment: thanks guys, it echoes a1b2c3 but still inserting blank data to the table, doesn't skip blank data.

Answer (score 0):

use [empty();](http://www.php.net/empty)

empty — Determine whether a variable is empty

```
 if(!empty($reference) && !empty($userDoc)) { Put your query } .
```